# Proving matrix factorization using Schur complement

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, pseudoinverse, schur-complement

In my studies of matrix analysis I came across this problem:

> Let $ A $ be a real symmetric matrix which is also positive semidefinite and we are asked to prove, by induction on the dimension of $ A $ that there exist the following factorization $ A=LL^T $ and $ A=UU^T $ where $ L,U $ are lower and upper triangular matrices, respectively. We are instructed to prove this fact using the Schur complement, which is defined for the following block matrix $ A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
> B & C \\
> C^T & E \end{array} \right)  $ where $ E $ is principal square submatrix of $ A $ the Schur complement is defined as $ A/E = B-CE^{\dagger}C^T $ where $E^{\dagger}$ is the Moore-Penrose generalized inverse.

To be honest I have no idea how to prove this factorization using the assumption A is positive semidefinite and I have no idea how to carry out the induction using the Schur complement. I appreciate all help on this.

Comment: I think this: https://wiki.math.ntnu.no/_media/ma2501/2014v/cholesky.pdf presents quite well the reasoning you're looking for.